# Creating a new time column in PostGIS / CartoDB

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto

I received a CSV file that has year (just two digits, '70'), month (as 'JAN'), day and time (as '0310') as separate columns. Bringing in to CartoDB / PostGIS they all appear as strings. I'd like to convert them to a single column that is a real 'date' type so I can display with Torque. What's the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: Mixing time with months may not be helpful given that it would all wash out in torque. I can give it a shot though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd give this a shot.

First, create a new column, called mydates with type date. Then do the following SQL (replacing names of columns and your table where appropriate),

```
UPDATE mytable SET 
mydates = to_date(month_column || year_column || time_column, 'MonYYHH12MI')
```

That assumes you have a 12 hour clock. If it is 24 hour clock, do this,

```
UPDATE mytable SET 
mydates = to_date(month_column || year_column || time_column, 'MonYYHH24MI')
```

Comment: and if you did actually need the times, use `to_timestamp` with everything else the same.

Comment: Looks like that forgets the day. Would day be done like: `UPDATE final_seadab_geo_only SET 
mission_date = to_date(hotel_day_of_mission || hotel_month_of_mission || hotel_year_of_mission || time_over_target, 'DDMonYYHH24MI')` ?

Comment: That said it looks like my data is a bit too messy for this to work, it hits some that don't have a field for all of those. Is there some way to make it just do null if it hits a case it can't parse?